# Getting services status via SC command instead of powershell

Tags: powershell

What's equivalent SC command for below powershell script ?

```
Get-Service -ComputerName localhost -Name Spooler | select machinename,name,starttype,status
```

Comment: Get together output from `sc.exe query Spooler`, `sc.exe queryex Spooler` and `sc.exe qc Spooler`.

Comment: @JosefZ  can you give me sample script? thanks

Answer (score 2):

Use the `qc` command to query the service config for the startup type and name:

```
~> sc.exe qc spooler

SERVICE_NAME: spooler
        TYPE               : 110  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS (interactive)
        START_TYPE         : 4   DISABLED
        ERROR_CONTROL      : 1   NORMAL
        BINARY_PATH_NAME   : C:\WINDOWS\System32\spoolsv.exe
        LOAD_ORDER_GROUP   : SpoolerGroup
        TAG                : 0
        DISPLAY_NAME       : Print Spooler
        DEPENDENCIES       : RPCSS
                           : http
        SERVICE_START_NAME : LocalSystem
```

Use the `query` or `queryex` commands to fetch the status:

```
~> sc.exe query spooler

SERVICE_NAME: spooler
        TYPE               : 110  WIN32_OWN_PROCESS  (interactive)
        STATE              : 1  STOPPED
        WIN32_EXIT_CODE    : 1077  (0x435)
        SERVICE_EXIT_CODE  : 0  (0x0)
        CHECKPOINT         : 0x0
        WAIT_HINT          : 0x0
```

Comment: so how can I get similar result to the output of powershell script ? machinename,name,starttype,status

Comment: @Arbelac By running the PowerShell script. Why are you so intent on recreating the output you already have with `sc.exe`?

Answer (score 0):

Since you tagged only powershell one must assume you're running sc.exe in powershell. I would like to understand why you aren't just using Get-Service? In case you have a real need/valid reason for it, you can try this function.

```
Function Get-SC {
    [cmdletbinding()]
    Param(
        [parameter(Position=0)]
        $Service,
    
        [parameter(Position=1)]
        $Computer = 'Localhost'
    )

    $StartTypeLookup = @{
        AUTO_START   = 'Automatic'
        DEMAND_START = 'Manual'
        DISABLED     = 'Disabled'
    }

    switch -Regex (sc.exe \\$computer qc $service){
        'DISPLAY_NAME\s+:\s(.+)' {$name = $matches.1}
        'START_TYPE[\s\d:]+\s+(\w+)' {$starttype = $StartTypeLookup[$matches.1]}
    }

    $state = switch -Regex (sc.exe \\$computer query $service){
        'STATE\s+.+?(\w+)\s*$' {$matches.1}
    }

    [PSCustomObject]@{
        MachineName = $computer
        DisplayName = $name
        Name        = $Service
        StartType   = $starttype
        Status      = $state
    }
}
```

Some testing and results

**Example 1**

```
Get-SC WpcMonSvc

MachineName : Localhost
DisplayName : Parental Controls
Name        : WpcMonSvc
StartType   : Automatic
Status      : STOPPED
```

**Example 2**

```
Get-SC -Computer kids1 -Service spooler

MachineName : kids1
DisplayName : Print Spooler
Name        : spooler
StartType   : Automatic
Status      : RUNNING
```